# Displaying lots of images without storing them as byte data?

Tags: android, bitmap, byte, inputstream

Ive been using various lazy loading techniques for images and other things. It works but I was wondering if there is a better way that some one knows of for getting an image from a server/webservice/whatever that doesnt require as much memory or time to download. The reason I ask is because I have an overseas developer asking me to rebuild a webservice for a project and hes asking me to allow them to just use a url to get the image. My thought was that whether its a url or a post to a service the result still has to come back via an inputstream which is going to take up the same memory whether virtual or stored in hard storage. His question had me slightly confused so out of curiosity Im asking on here......is there a way to get an image without using an inputstream? I guess it would be like a calorie free image lol.

Comment: You're right - as an image consists of colored pixels, these pixel-data will somehow be needed at the place where the image is to be shown. There are many ways how to pass the image from A to B, but if you want it to be shown at B, you'll have to get the data there.

Comment: lol I knew I wasnt crazy....I thought maybe after all these years I had missed some key technique that others were using. If anyone else has something to say otherwise please do so.

Comment: Nah, there's no magic here :-) What you can do however is, if the client only needs a small version of an image, that you scale the image on the server-side so to reduce the amount of data to be transfered.

Comment: Yeah Ive done that. I have various sizes stored in directories. I thought maybe there was a possibility that the image data could magically "go away" after it was displayed just leaving a visual ghost of itself lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can blit the big image into a small image and discard the big one. This is how thumbnails work in image programs.

Comment: Ive already done that on the server. I only send small images out to devices on request. I was just wondering if what the overseas developer had told me was actually possible and that was to display an image without needing the data or in other words getting the stream, showing the picture, getting rid of the data but keeping the image on screen.